# Jasmine how to test functions which returns httpClient observable?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, jasmine, karma-runner

I have a function inside a component like below

```
  getProperties(data) {
    let type = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('type');
    const types = {
      "easy": {
        adviceEndpoint: this.apiService.getEasy(),
      }, "medium": {
        adviceEndpoint: this.apiService.getMedium(),
      }
    }
    return types[type];
  }
```

`apiService` return `httpClient` methods such as get,post etc.I injected successfully all dependencies as you can see above.Interestingly I can pick one of types and returns adviceEndpoint and adviceFeatures but it can't get adviceEndpoint,it returns as undefined like below when I print it to console `Object{adviceEndpoint: undefined}`

```
   fdescribe('ExampleComponent', () => {
        let component: ExampleComponent;
        let fixture: ComponentFixture<ExampleComponent>;
        let el: DebugElement;
        let route: any;
        beforeEach(async(() => {
            const apiServiceSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('ApiService',
                ["getEasy", "getMedium"]
            );
            TestBed.configureTestingModule({
                imports: [NgbModule, CommonModule, RouterModule.forRoot([])],
                declarations: [ExampleComponent],
                providers: [
                    { provide: ApiService, useValue: apiServiceSpy },
                    {
                        provide: ActivatedRoute,
                        useValue: {
                            snapshot: {
                                paramMap: convertToParamMap({ type: 'easy' })
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }).compileComponents().then(() => {
                fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ExampleComponent);
                route = TestBed.inject(ActivatedRoute);
                component = fixture.componentInstance;
                el = fixture.debugElement;
                fixture.detectChanges();
            });
        }));
        it("should return true properties", () => {
            const properties = component.getProperties();
            console.log(properties);
            //Object{adviceEndpoint: undefined}
        });
    });
```

Comment: from what I can see I don't think this `let type = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('type');` is returning "easy" or "medium" from the test, you need to mock that route and return whichever you are testing, easy or medium

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are not trying to test your ApiService mock inside of tests for ExampleComponent. if so, then just provide some mock values, so you could check for correct object in the end

```
it("should return true properties", () => {
  apiServiceSpy.getEasy.and.returnValue('easy-endpoint');
   const properties = component.getProperties();
   expect(properties).toEqual({adviceEndpoint: 'easy-endpoint'});
});
```

Comment: I need that easy-endpoint to return an observable something like this.http.get(....).I just want to check if it returns correct function

Comment: are you sure you need this? We are duscussing `ExampleComponent`s tests. and there is no real ApiService implementation inside of this code, just a mock in your `apiServiceSpy`.  you can return anything from this spy, even an observable, but I would test it with strings for simplicity

Comment: Actually you are right providing string would be good enough